# Discord API : how do I get the invite code?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

My question seems pretty simple but i'm starting to doubt it's even possible after hours of head scratching.

**I created an invite link for a private channel (based on roles) .If someone uses that link i want to automatically add her/him the necessary role so s/he can read/write to that channel.**

I see two ways of doing this, either get the invite code or get the channel ID the user lands to.

I tried both for hours with no success.
I saw some topics mentioning a message content that would contain the invite link without much context so i don't know when they get that *(when creating an invite link i guess)*. One thing's sure i never get it when joining a guild/channel by clicking an invite link.
And unless the user sends a message i see no way to know the channel ID s/he lands to.

I logged all the raw events data and saw nothing helpful.

Should i simply give up? :(

Have a good day!

Comment: I just thought about another solution that is to keep track of the invite link clicks and when someone joins see if it incremented. As i don't plan to get many clicks on this link that should be viable.
But I would really love not to endup doing this T_T